# What pattern do I need to use to split in between characters?

Tags: python, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

Consider the string `s`:

```
s = ';hello@;earth@;hello@;mars@'
```

I want a pattern `pat` such that I get

```
re.split(pat, s)

[';hello@', ';earth@', ';hello@', ';mars@']
```

I want the `;` and `@` to remain in the result strings, but I know I want to split in between them.

I thought I could use a lookahead and lookbehind:

```
re.split('(?<=@)(?=;)', s)
```

However, it resulted in an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-392-27c8b02c2477> in <module>()
----> 1 re.split('(?<=@)(?=;)', s)

//anaconda/envs/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py in split(pattern, string, maxsplit, flags)
    210     and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element
    211     of the list."""
--> 212     return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
    213 
    214 def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):

ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
```

Comment: You can also use `[';' + k for k in s.split(";") if k != '']`. It's not a regex but can give you the same desired output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is really quite eloquent: [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) requires a non-empty pattern match.

> Note that `split` will never split a string on an empty pattern match.

You may match them:

```
re.findall(r';\w+@', s)
```

or

```
re.findall(r';[^@]+@', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e6tMg7/2)

The `re.findall` will find all non-overlapping occurrences of the matching pattern.

The `;[^@]+@` pattern will find `;` followed with 1+ symbols other than `@` and then will match `@`, so both `;` and `@` will be inside the returned items.

Answer (score 2):

The re module doesn't allow to split on an empty match. You can use the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) with this pattern to do it:

```
regex.split(r'(?V1)(?<=@)(?=;)', s)
```

The `(?V1)` modifier switches to the new behaviour.

---

To have the same result with re you can use `re.findall` with this pattern:

```
re.findall(r'(?:;|^)[^@]*@*', s)
```

Comment: @piRSquared: I have permuted `@` and `;` in the first pattern. <°)))))>

Comment: Confirmed... this works as claimed...  Thank you.  I went with `re` because its easier to access since I had to go and install `regex`.  But this was an accurate answer.

Comment: @piRSquared: note that the `re.findall` pattern is build to mimic the split pattern even in edge cases: `abc@;def@@@;ghi` => `['abc@', ';def@@@', ';ghi']`